# Assembly Language Array

Tags: arrays, assembly, mips

Any help to find the answer would be greatly appreciated.

```
.data
array: .word 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10
.text
.globl main 
main:
   la $t0, array
   li $t1, 4
   mult $t1, $t1
   mflo $t1
   add $t0, $t0, $t1
   sw $t1, 20($t0)
```

What are the values of the array after executing the instructions? Im confused on this part. Do I just add 20 to each value in the array?

Comment: Why not run the code and see for yourself ?

Comment: At the moment I cant because im using my phone to post this. I sent my laptop in for repairs and wont have access to a laptop until Wednesday.

Comment: You could always try one of the various [online MIPS simulators](http://morriswmz.jit.su/static/simple-mips-pipelined.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some hints

```
.data
array: .word 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10 # 10 32 bits values @array
.text
.globl main 
main:
   la $t0, array      # Load address of array into $t0
   li $t1, 4          # Load constant 4 into $t1
   mult $t1, $t1      # Multiply $t1 x $t1
   mflo $t1           # Put result (lower word) into $t1 ( 16 )
   add $t0, $t0, $t1  # $t0 = $t0 + $t1 ( array + 16 )
   sw $t1, 20($t0)    # Store $t1 at address ( $t0 + 20 )
```

Provided that a word is 4 bytes, i.e. storing at (array + 4) overwrites the `2` in array (2<sup>nd</sup> value), you should be able to figure out the answer to your question.